# How to say "I told him that XXX"?

Tags: spoken-language

I have a question regarding the word "tell/told"
I want to say "I told him that XXX"
After some research, this is what I came up with.

> 彼に「XXX」を伝えた。
>
> 彼に「XXX」を言った。

I was wondering if they both have different level of formality? or which one is better use with friend?

EDIT: I still don't understand it, after reading the [suggested duplicate question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3862/when-to-use-say-speak-tell-or-express). However, this is better elaborated by the answer below.

Thank you

Comment: Try looking into the quotation particle 「と」, as in 「彼にｘｘｘと言った」

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the difference between 伝えるand言うis one of formality.

伝えるhas the connotation of "passing on a message", or "informing someone". It suggests that the speaker didn't create the message, they're just passing it on.

言うis simply "to say" something or "to tell" someone something.